# Convert PPT to PDF while adding in slide numbers

Tags: pdf, applescript, powerpoint

I have powerpoints that I need to convert to PDFs. I have the code to be able to convert the PPT to a PDF, but I would also like the script to add in the slide numbers before turning the PPT into a PDF. Is this possible by using an apple script? The slide number variable exists, but I am having trouble using it.

Comment: It’s not clear in your question whether the code to convert your PPT to PDF is also in AppleScript.  If so, it might be useful to include it in your question, if it’s not too long and if you have permission to do so from whomever authored the script.  From there, inserting slide numbers ought to be easy.  Also, what specifically about the slide number AppleScript variable are you having trouble with ?  What did you try, can you provide a sample of your own script ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! SO is not a code writing service and if you want help debugging code, your question really needs to conform to [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).